# FIFA 18 gets stuck with the music still running

Tags: technical-issues, fifa-18

I recently downloaded and installed FIFA 18 FitGirl Repack (cuz I have a normal computer that can't run any further FIFAs T-T). Now the only problem is that in the game, there seems to be an error. The game runs properly but after some minutes (like 5-10 minutes), the game freezes wherever it is in the menu. However, the music continues playing.

I have re-installed the game but the error remains. I have also checked several gaming forums for a solution but can't find one. If you know how to resolve this, do let me know. Also, if there is some other info regarding the game files that you need, let me know in the comments. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am running the game on Windows 10 with DirectX 11.